SonarLint on Optional.ofNullable: A "NullPointerException" could be thrown
I am getting sonar warning A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "test" is nullable here. inside the if condition:
public record Test(String x) {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test("x");
    printXLength(test);
  }

  private static void printXLength(Test test) {
    if (Optional.ofNullable(test).map(test1 -> test1.x).isPresent()) {
      System.out.println(test.x.length());
    }
  }
}

I set the test variable to null and ran it, it didn't throw NPE.
Is it false positive ? Or am I missing something?

Can you show the code to test with Null ? if parameter test is null test1.x will throw an NPE

you might want to set the x property of Test object to be an Optional

On this line:
if (Optional.ofNullable(test).map(test1 -> test1.x).isPresent())

the call to isPresent() doesn't directly check if test is present; it checks if the result of the map call is present - hence it only checks the presence of test indirectly. Sonarlint is not clever enough to go through all the data flow involved to determine that test itself can't be null here.
Try changing it to the following:
  private static void printXLength(Test test) {
    Optional.ofNullable(test).map(test1 -> test1.x).ifPresent(
      x -> System.out.println(x.length())
    )
  }


the lamba code works, but does that mean I cannot use Optional.ofNullable with if and should go back to traditional null check : if(test != null && test.x() != null) ?

If you want to use if(...isPresent()) then you'll have to turn off the SonarLint check using the comment //NOSONAR

so basically this issue is False Positive?

It could be called a false positive, even though it would be unfair to expect Sonar to figure it out.
